# Difference between desktop and mobile when displaying DWG files

Tags: android, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I am currently developing a mobile drawing viewer using the Autodesk Forge API.

The following two output the same drawing.

The output from the PC browser looks just like case1.

However, in the mobile browser, the "round" part is not displayed normally as in case2.

Is there a solution?

[image]

Comment: What version of Viewer is this and which mobile browser? Did you try Chrome/Firefox? If the issue persists can you send the drawing (via a sharing service e.g. weTransfer/Dropbox/GDrtive) to forge.help@autodesk.com so we can look into this?